# how to expand and collapse the textView which is having EditText as its child

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

i am new to android..In my xml file i have used three textviews,
inside that i have used three edittext for every textview..
what i want is when i press a particular textview it has to expand to get their 
child(edittexts)..and when i again press the textview should collapse back.

Now in my code when i press textview it expands,but when i press again its not collapsing.

Below is my code..any help would be appreciated...thanks in advance..

## Java file

CategoryPage.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CategoryPage extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_page);

    TextView btnProfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnprofile);
    TextView btnSettings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btncitizen);
    TextView btnPrivacy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnprivacy);

    View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
    panelProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
    panelSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
    panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // DO STUFF
            View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
            panelProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
            panelSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
            panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // DO STUFF
            View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
            panelProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
            panelSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
            panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    btnPrivacy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // DO STUFF
            View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
            panelProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
            panelSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
            panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

## XML File

activity_category_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/miiskylogo" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

<LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/root_layout" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/Text"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
            android:text="@string/Text2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnprofile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
    android:text="Profile Vault"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/panelProfile"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelProfile1"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/salutation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.81"
                android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Salutation" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelProfile2"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/firstname" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="First Name"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelProfile3"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/middlename" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Middle Name"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelProfile4"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/lastname" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Last Name"  />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btncitizen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
    android:text="Citizenship/Registration"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/panelSettings"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelSettings1"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/currentaddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.81"
                android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Current address" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelSettings2"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/houseno" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="House no"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelSettings3"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/roadno" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Road no"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelSettings4"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/location" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Location"  />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnprivacy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
    android:text="Banking"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/panelPrivacy"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelPrivacy1"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bankacc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.81"
                android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Bank account no" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelPrivacy2"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/acctype" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Account Type"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelPrivacy3"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/bankcredit" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.81"
            android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Bank Credit Card No"  />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set Visibility to GONE for the EditText on Textview's click to collapse it.

Comment: hey thanks for the instant reply..but can u specify where exactly i have to do modification..?i am little bit confused.

Comment: You should use proper coading standard. Cause you declared textviews as it look like that its a instance of Button class. As my point of view we should start declaring textview with the txt prefix...... by the way You have to do it inside your Textview's click event i.e. inside onClick() method of btnSettings, btnPrivacy, btnProfile respectively.

Comment: Add code of below answer in it, it will be worked.

Comment: No its not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if view is visible or not `onClick` of TextView:

```
if(panelProfile.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    panelProfile.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
} else {
   panelProfile.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Note: You are declaring below code multiple times, instead just do it only once.

```
View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
```

same with,

```
View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
```

Comment: hey ur code neither expands nor collapse..the code that i have mentioned will expands once i press that txtview..but what i want is when it is exapnded,if i press the txtview again,it sholud collapse..

Comment: hey it is working like a charm..i have done some small modification to ur code..now it is working.